# Really stupid ATM...why can't I reference Master.FindControl?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

**`oPanel = CType(Master.FindControl("panelSearch"), Panel)`**

This code resides on my masterpage's back-end (**`theMaster.master.vb`**), but I get a "Cannot refer to an instance member from within a shared class or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

the function it resides in IS shared, I just can't remember for the life of me what I need to do to make this work.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Shared` modifier on your method that this code is written in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the Master property of the page from a shared function.  You must make the function an instance function (remove the Shared keyword) before you can use the Master property.